# initialization order of lambda as parameter which accepts other parameters

Tags: c++, lambda, move, move-semantics

I have a parameter (in this case std::vector) that I need to pass to an async method (preferably by move) and to a callback lambda.
Does the approach below guarantee that the lambda will be initialized first (implying vector being copied) so that I can move the vector to the async method?

```
Method(std::vector<std::string> vec)
{
    AsyncMethod(std::move(vec), [vec]() 
    {
        // act on vec
    });
}
```

Comment: As you didn't describe what you are trying to achive; Bare in mind, `vec` for your AsyncMethod and `vec` for your lambda are two different vectors, hence changing values in one does not affect the other...

Answer (score 3):

The order of evaluation of function parameter is unspecified, hence you can't rely on your assumption. A solution would be the following.

```
Method(std::vector<std::string> vec)
{
    auto l = [vec]() { /* Act on vec... */ };

    AsyncMethod(std::move(vec), l);
}
```

Depending on the signature of `AsyncMethod`, you might even want to pass the lambda as `std::move(l)`. This would again be safe, as the vector has been copied into the closure beforehand.

Comment: yeah, that's what I do at the moment. Not a big issue though. Just wanted to have more natural reading flow. Thanks